# Ng-click on Images, then showing information from database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database

I'm trying to do is, when an image is clicked I send an array with information into the function 'test', compare it with values from another database, and then I'm trying to return the correct infromation and display it. The code:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="hero in heroes | filter:search | orderBy:'id'">
  <div class="wrap">
   <img class="img-rounded" ng-src="images/heroes/{{hero.url}}_full.png" ng-click="test(hero.abilities)">
     <div class="tooltip"> 
        <p class="fat">{{hero.localizedName}}</p> 
     </div>
  </div>
</div>                    
 <div data-ng-repeat="ability in test| orderBy:'id'">
  {{ability.localizedName}} //Should show the information of the selected hero
 </div>
```

and the script,

```
$scope.test = function(text){
            var newSize = text.length;
            var temp = [];

            for(i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < $scope.abilities.length; j++)
                {
                    if($scope.abilities[j].id == text[i])
                    {
                    temp[i] = $scope.abilities[j];
                    }
                } 
            }
           //$scope.test = temp;
           console.log(temp);
        }
```

When I'm console logging out temp, I get the values that I desire, but I can't get the values back from the function.

The console only gives me error messages saying that

> "test" is not declared

, and I've search for that error message, but I don't seem to be able to find the answer that I'm searching for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $scope.test in the same controller as $scope.heros?

Comment: The $scope.heroes lies in the same controller, yes!

Comment: can you post your full controller?

Comment: added as an answer due to all the lines ^^

Comment: I noticed that you are using 'test' first as a function and second time as collection. Try attaching the test() result on $scope using a different name, after that you can iterate on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to repeat `test`:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="ability in test| orderBy:'id'">
```

but `test` is a funciton.

at the end of `test()` function, save `temp` on the `$scope`, for example:

```
$scope.arr = temp;
```

and change the template to repeat `arr`:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="ability in arr| orderBy:'id'">
```

Answer (score 0):

The full controller (with relevant code):

```
function AppController($filter, $log, $scope, dotaService, abilitiesService, itemsService)
       (..) 
     $scope.test = function(text){
                var newSize = text.length;
                var temp = [];

                for(i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
                {
                    for(j = 0; j < $scope.abilities.length; j++)
                    {
                        if($scope.abilities[j].id == text[i])
                        {
                        temp[i] = $scope.abilities[j];
                        }
                    } 
                }
               //$scope.test = temp;
               console.log(temp);

            //Heroes
            var promise = dotaService.getHeroes();
            promise.then(function (data)
            {
                $scope.heroes = data.data;
            })
            //Abilites
            var promise2 = abilitiesService.getAbilities();
            promise2.then(function (data)
            {
                $scope.abilities = data.data;
            });          
        }
```